# Losing Precision on purpose

Tags: java, casting, ide, int, double

While converting double to int:

```
double d = 5.5;
int i = (int) d;
```

Variable "i" becomes 5. That's exactly what i want, the problem is i am getting the warning: Cast to 'int' from 'double' may result in loss of precision
My question is, is there any way to tell IDE that such precision loss is expected so i will not get the warning?
So is there any other way to lose precision and cast to integer?

I know that i could disable all loss precision warnings at all, but it wouldn't be nice.
I am using Intellij IDEA 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing is to use Double and Integer. Then you can use intValue() method.

Comment: So it would look like that: int i = new Double(5.5).intValue(); Speed of this operation would be same as normal casting?

Comment: Yes it looks like you wrote. Concerning about speed of this operation is unnecessary because it doesn't contain any complex instructions.

Comment: @user3009344: there will be some overhead of object creation.

Answer (score 6):

Consider adding **@SuppressWarnings("NumericCastThatLosesPrecision")** on your method. This would be a portable solution to your concern.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/suppressing-inspections.html explains a graphical way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this inspection in Idea for whole project.

Main menu -> Analyze -> Configure current file analisys -> Configure inspections

Use the Seach to find "Numeric cast that loses precision" inspection and uncheck it.

Comment: Yes but as i said it wouldn't be nice. Sometimes such warnings can help.

Comment: Then you should annotate you methed with @SuppressWarnings("NumericCastThatLosesPrecision")

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want do declare another variable "i" ..
I mean you can directly use "(int) d" where ever you want,that way you also save some memory.